# Eclipse debug stepping not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to develop Java program and I had to downgrade from JRE/JDK 1.7.x to JRE/JDK 1.6.

When I am stepping through and when it calls a new class, I am either getting source not found or not going into the new class.  For example,

```
//Here, it doesn't go to the Another class
MyClass class = new AnotherClass(value1, value2);
```

Any idea?

Comment: which specific version of the jdk are you running? ie: "1.6.0_29". Run `java -version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try going into 'AnotherClass' and get the Source Not Found, there should be an 'Attach Source' button. Try clicking on it, and when prompted choose the project which contains the source for 'AnotherClass'.

Do this even if AnotherClass is in the current project. If it works, kindly let us know and we'll try to figure out what the original problem might be.

Also, your mileage may vary, but try doing the debugging for a brand new project and see what happens ?

Comment: Yes, the AnotherClass is in the same workspace as in the MyClass.  Interesting is that I tried to put a breakpoint in the AnotherClass and I can't seem to do that but I can see the AnotherClass fine in Ecilipse.

Comment: Something weird is going on. Check the following eclipse preference : Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Compiler --> Classfile Generation. Is the "Add line number attributes to generated class file" checked ?

Comment: Also, can you check your Eclipse Error log to see whether errors are generated immediately after you try putting a breakpoint ?  To open up the error log, use this keyboard shortcut `Alt Shift Q,Q` and then type in Error Log.

Comment: Yes, the checkbox is checked. So now, I can only go to another class only if I put a breakpoint (This is fixed now) in another class otherwise, it wont even go into the another class. Any idea?

Comment: Tony, if this is acceptable to you we could do a Screen share using join.me to figure this out. I think if I could get a look at your eclipse setup it would be much more useful. Let me know if you are up for it. If so, go to join.me -> Click on 'Basic' -> And then Click on the ORANGE 'play' button. You should get a numeric code which I can use to see your screen. If you wanna go ahead, mail me the code on foxtrot_ixcr@TrashMail.net  (This is a temp mail address I just generated using Firefox' trashmail addon)

Answer (score 0):

In general, things to check:

1. You have the correct source attached, and, if you're specifying an external directory, at the correct directory level.  It will be the directory above the top package of AnotherClass.
2. If you're attaching source from another project that contains AnotherClass, make sure it was compiled with debugging symbols on.